# И вновь регулярные выражения.

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Я уже давненько использую txt2re.com, меня всегда все устраивало. Но вот с последним попадос. 
Нужно мне данные вот от таких строк:

```
root      15227  0.0  0.0   3956   600 ?        S    22:19   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep 31114 2>&1
root      15229  0.0  0.0   6028   696 ?        S    22:19   0:00 grep 31114
root      31114  0.1  0.0  50632  9848 pts/0    S+   00:43   1:30 ./linux start 60
```

Соответственно, зная 31114, мне нужно:
пользователь (сейчас он root), вот эти 0.1  0.0  50632  9848 статус (S+ или другие, которые бывают). Время запуска 00:43 (тут вот как раз у меня и косяк, так как там может быть так: Nov26) дальше вот это время 1:30 и значение запуска, в данном случае 60.
Ребята помогите. :(

Comment: Nov26 - вместо времени может быть дата в формате 3 буквы-месяц и число)?
Предоставьте, пожалуйста, больше информации.

Comment: да, заместо времени месяц и число. Aug,Oct,Nov,Dec

Comment: На самом деле там (время или дата запуска) всегда одно поле (без пробелов). 

Т.е. у Вас каждая строка содержит 10 полей плюс хвост (команда и параметры). Неужели ПХП не может распарсить такую структуру данных, например, в массив?


В чем именно проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаю [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) - регулярки в данном случае не нужны. Но если очень сильно хочется, то можно. Где-то так:

```
^(?'user'.{8})(?'pid'.{7})(.{5})(.{5})(.{7})(.{6})(.{7})(.{6})(.{7})(.{7})(.*)$
```

(я специально использовал именные группы, чтобы показать, что так можно). Да, к значениям потом нужно приложить trim или что там есть в php.

Если совсем по хорошему, то нужно смотреть на первую строку, считать кол-во полей, а потом сплитить по пробелам строку.

```
split('\s+', $line, 11)
```

11 - это кол-во столбцов.

Пример кода

```
<?php
$lines = file('list.txt');

$num = 0;
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    if ($line_num == 0) {
        $cap = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
        $num = count($cap);
        print "num = $num\n";
    } else {
        print "num = $num\n";
        $data = preg_split('/\s+/', $line, $num);
        print "$cap[2] - $data[2]\n";
    }
}

?>
```